# Fusioncharts XT Hovereffect only works on the half chart

Tags: xml, json, charts, hover, fusioncharts

I've got a Multi-Series Chart, which only shows animation on the left side of the chart. The showTooltip works well, as long it's on the left side but when you move over the anchors on the right side, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know this error?

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle:

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'line',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '500',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Visitors to website",
                "subCaption": "Last week",
                "xAxisName": "Day",
                "yAxisName": "Visits",
                "theme": "fint",
                //Additional anchor hover cosmetics attributes
                "anchorBgHoverColor": "#96d7fa",                
                "anchorBorderHoverThickness" : "4",
                "anchorHoverRadius":"7"               
            },
            "data": [{
                "label": "Mon",
                "value": "5123"
            }, {
                "label": "Tue",
                "value": "4233"
            }, {
                "label": "Wed",
                "value": "5507"
            }, {
                "label": "Thu",
                "value": "4110"
            }, {
                "label": "Fri",
                "value": "5529"
            }, {
                "label": "Sat",
                "value": "5803"
            }, {
                "label": "Sun",
                "value": "6202"
            }]
        }
    }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>

<!-- Using Hover effect on anchors for line charts. Roll over the anchors to see the effect.  

Attributes : 
    # plotHoverEffect - Set to 1
    //Following attributes helps to configure the anchor cosmetics on hover

    # anchorBgHoverColor - Background color of anchor upon hover
    # anchorBorderHoverColor - Border color of anchor upon hover (Not used in this sample) 
    # anchorBorderHoverThickness - Border thickness of anchor upon hover
    # anchorHoverRadius - Radius of anchor upon hover
-->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/BQUw4/

Hover effect is visible on both left/right side of the canvas area. Share the data here to replicate the issue.

Comment: Sadly the code works when i use it in JSFiddle. I think there is a problem in another part of the code. I thought, maybe there is someone, who already had a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the code given above in the Fiddle, and it is working fine even when I am trying it outside the Fiddle.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
            var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'line',
                renderAt: 'chart-container',
                width: '500',
                height: '300',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "Visitors to website",
                        "subCaption": "Last week",
                        "xAxisName": "Day",
                        "yAxisName": "Visits",
                        "theme": "fint",
                        "anchorBgHoverColor": "#96d7fa",
                        "anchorBorderHoverThickness": "4",
                        "anchorHoverRadius": "7"
                    },
                    "data": [{
                        "label": "Mon",
                        "value": "5123"
                    }, {
                        "label": "Tue",
                        "value": "4233"
                    }, {
                        "label": "Wed",
                        "value": "5507"
                    }, {
                        "label": "Thu",
                        "value": "4110"
                    }, {
                        "label": "Fri",
                        "value": "5529"
                    }, {
                        "label": "Sat",
                        "value": "5803"
                    }, {
                        "label": "Sun",
                        "value": "6202"
                    }]
                }
            }).render();
        });
```

You can even try out different types of Line Charts In [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-chart-fiddles/?charts&chart=Line--Chart).